# HTML5 <video> tag for ogv file not work in Mozilla . Any better solution?

Tags: html, mozilla, html5-video

There is a problem with firefox. Lot of questions there related this but i didnt get any solution for it. In this link video tag's video not working in mozilla and in crome its working fine. **type='video/ogg'** added but no luck yet.

Comment: Works fine for me in firefox. `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0`

Comment: my `windows/7, firefox/28.0` not working at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to check browser and load best format only...

I consider webm is better for Firefox or Chrome.. For anything else, you can use mp4.

Just like this :

Your HTML :

```
<video id="frog" loop autoplay ></video>
```

Your JS :

```
    $(window).load(function(){
       var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
       var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
       if(is_firefox || is_chrome){
         // for firefox or chrome, webm is better
           $("#frog").attr("src","http://www.ellevation.com.au/sanli/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/testvid_VP8.webm");
       }else{
           $("#frog").attr("src","http://www.ellevation.com.au/sanli/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/testvid_x264.mp4");
       }
    });
```

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4umL/4/).

**Edit :** (september 2014)

It seems that Firefox no longer supports webm format on html5 video.

Best solution seems :

HTML :

```
<video controls>
    <source src="oggVideoPath.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="mp4VideoPath.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser doesn't support <code>video</code>.
</video>
```

And BEST SOLUTION to correctly encode mp4 to Ogg Theora is :

http://v2v.cc/~j/ffmpeg2theora/

very easy to use, install it and just write this command line : 
ffmpeg2theora mp4VideoPath.mp4

Comment: Is there any way with that it can also play in safari browser ?

Comment: Normally mp4 works in Safari browser.
I think it's the video,try to encode it again in mp4... (for example, I use Miro Video Converter)

I tried it and it's work : http://jsfiddle.net/j4umL/7/

Answer (score 0):

When I try to open the page, it uses the mp4 version, so I cannot be certain about this.
But it could be that your webserver does not return the correct `Content-Type`-header for the ogg media stream.

It must return `media/ogg` for it to work properly on all browsers and platforms.

Comment: `http://www.ellevation.com.au/sanli/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/testvid_libtheora.ogv` this video used. Its working fine if we direct run this in firefox.

Comment: It seems to give the correct `Content-Type`, so unfortunately that is not it. If you install the ogg/vorbis codec on windows, does it work then?

Comment: Ok, so please let me know. Is there any solution for it am not familiar with this issue like `"Content-Type"` ?